# Custom event fired but not triggered

Tags: vue.js

I have two components and I am trying to save data from one component into another but somehow the event isn't triggered by the parent component. I see no errors in the code must be something else.

When I add newTask I emit "some" event but is not triggering on the parent

App.vue file

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <Form></Form>
  <div @some="some">
    <Task :tasks="tasks" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "./components/Form.vue";
import Task from "./components/Task.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    Task,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      message: "This is my first taks",
      tasks: [
        { status: "To do", title: "Some task not solved" },
        { status: "Done", title: "Make shopping" },
        { status: "Blocked", title: "That blocked" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    some() {
      console.log("event fired");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Form.vue

````
<template>
  <input type="text" placeholder="new task" v-model="task" />
  <button @click="addTask">Add new Task</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      task: "",
      tasks: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTask() {
      //  console.log(this.task);
      this.$emit("some", this.task);
    },
  },
};
</script>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your EventListener to the component from where the event is firing. And in your code it's the `Task` Component. So instead of listening from the div you may code like this,

```
<Task :tasks="tasks" @some="some" />
```